# Changing the antd Calendar component date through a completely separate button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a component that uses the antd Calendar component, which comes with it's own header to navigate through it as seen in the [docs](https://ant.design/components/calendar). However, I need to manipulate which month/year the calendar is displaying through a completely separate component. I know I can customize it's header, but for what I am doing, it isn't the solution.

Anyway, what I want to know is what I have to pass in to set which month and year I want to display on the calendar and change it as I please.

```js
function MyCalendar () {
  const [month, changeMonth] = useState(10)
  const [year, changeYear] = useState(2019)
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => changeMonth(0)}>Change month to January</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => changeYear(1990)}>Change year to 1900</Button>
      <Calendar
        // what do I pass in to chose the month/year being displayed base on month and year??
        // value={new Date(`${year}/${month}/01`)}
        mode='month'
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

I should probably note that I know that the `value` prop is used to select a specific date and it shows the month and year that you pass in, but I don't want to change the selected date cell, that needs to be kept for the current day. So I guess I need to keep the selected cell whichever the day is, but change the display of month and year according to the `month` and `year` state.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, what you expect to see when you change a month? Nothing to be selected because you predefined the selected day? So why just not control the selected day to appear on matched month?

Comment: Basically I want to change the month and year, but not change the selected day with it. The selected day needs to stay on today regardless of where we go.